# How do I combine multiple rows in SQL(oracle) using LISTAGG and multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement that returns data that looks like this:

```
SOURCEDID   ORGSOURCEDIDS   ROLE    USERNAME    EMAIL   GIVENNAME   FAMILYNAME
123456  0   teacher test.teacher@   test.teacher@   Test    Teacher
123456  1802    teacher test.teacher@test.teacher@  Test    Teacher
123456  1803    teacher test.teacher@   test.teacher@   Test    Teacher
123456  1804    teacher test.teacher@   test.teacher@   Test    Teacher
```

I am trying to get rows with the same 'SOURCEDID' to combine into one row with 'ORGSOURCEDIDS' in a comma separated list such as: '0,1802,1803,1804'. All the other data besides ORGSOURCEDIDS is always the same (the system creates and update separate records at each org when you edit any one of the records).

I am trying to use the following SQL:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TEACHERNUMBER) as sourcedId, 
   LISTAGG(schoolid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY schoolid) orgSourcedIds
FROM teachers 
group by TEACHERNUMBER
```

Which does give me something like this:

```
SOURCEDID   ORGSOURCEDIDS
123456  0,1802,1803,1804
```

But I can't figure out how to add back in the other columns that don't change (role, username, email, givenname, familyname) from the example above. If I try to add other columns I get "not a GROUP BY expression".

I also tried something like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TEACHERNUMBER) as sourcedId, 
   LISTAGG(schoolid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY schoolid) orgSourcedIds,
   LISTAGG(EMAIL_ADDR, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL_ADDR) EMAIL_ADDR
FROM teachers 
group by TEACHERNUMBER
order by TEACHERNUMBER;
```

which returns something like this:

```
SOURCEDID   ORGSOURCEDIDS   EMAIL_ADDR
123456  0,1802,1803,1804    test.teacher@,test.teacher@,test.teacher@,test.teacher@
```

But in my case, EMAIL_ADDR will always be the same for each row with the same SOURCEDID, so using LISTAGG on that field doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TEACHERNUMBER) as sourcedId, 
       LISTAGG(schoolid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY schoolid) as orgSourcedIds,
       ROLE, USERNAME, EMAIL, GIVENNAME, FAMILYNAME
FROM teachers 
GROUP BY TEACHERNUMBER, ROLE, USERNAME, EMAIL, GIVENNAME, FAMILYNAME
```

Comment: So simple, I knew I had to be missing something stupid, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Listagg` is an aggregate function so for the rest of columns you have to **1)** move them to `group by` clause, as proposed by @GordonLinoff or **2)** use any aggregate function, for instance `max()` or **3)** check if they repeat and if yes - use `listagg()`, if no - use `max()`:

```
-- sample data
with t(sourcedid, orgsourcedids, role, email) as (
    select 123456,    0, 'teacher1', 'test@teachers.org' from dual union all
    select 123456, 1802, 'teacher2', 'test@teachers.org' from dual union all
    select 123456, 1803, 'teacher1', 'test@teachers.org' from dual union all
    select 123456, 1804, 'teacher1', 'test@teachers.org' from dual )
-- end of sample data
select sourcedid, 
       listagg(orgsourcedids, ', ') within group (order by orgsourcedids) orgs, 
       case when count(distinct role) > 1 
            then listagg(role, ', ') within group (order by orgsourcedids) 
            else max(role) end roles,
       case when count(distinct email) > 1 
            then listagg(email, ', ') within group (order by orgsourcedids) 
            else max(email) end emails       
  from t
  group by sourcedid
```

Result:

```
 SOURCEDID ORGS                 ROLES                                   EMAILS
---------- -------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------
    123456 0, 1802, 1803, 1804  teacher1, teacher2, teacher1, teacher1  test@teachers.org
```

Roles are different, so they are presented as list, email is common so it's only one.